# ConfirmationCode is not getting invalid in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When i use the UserInformationRecoveryService verifyConfirmation Code web service,it should get invalid after it is verified once.We are sending askPassword email after creating a user.User should be able to use that confirmation code only once.

Is there any config need to be modified.??

Comment: So can you change set your password more than once by using same link in an email?

Comment: Yes. The verifyConfirmationCode returns the key as many times you verify it.We pass this key to updatePassword webservice.But think it should have thrown error when i verify the confirmationCode

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand what you have meant here. I think you are refering to https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Recover+with+Notification. So you are calling verifyConfirmationCode two times with same confirmation code and get two new codes? Is that what you meant here? And from them, only one new key was working and other threw and error? Is that what happened?

Comment: We registerUser as Admin using RemoteUserStoreManagerClient addUser with ask password which sends email with confirmation code.We verify this code using UserInformationRecoveryUtil verify confirmation Code..Once we verify the confirmation code shlould become invalid.If i try again to verify theat confirmation code also it works

Comment: @Althaf hey, did you ever figure this out? We are running IS 5.10.0 and our email links are not invalidating either after the first use. I'm sorry to resurrect such an old question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently confirmation codes retrieved at password reset will be only invalidated at successful password reset or at confirmation code expiration. Please follow details [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3175).

As far as I remember, we had a plan to make this configurable, but from the jira I can't find that we have implemented it or not, so most likely we haven't done that yet.

Comment: We use updatePassword in  UserInformationRecoveryService  to reset password.But that does not invalidate the confirmation code.Anyother web service to update password??

Comment: After updating password it should invalidate the confirmation code, if it is not happening please report a jira.

Comment: So after updating password,it should have thrown error during verifyConfirmationCode() right